# Sorting the dropdown list

Tags: asp.net

I have a dropdownlist dynamically filled from file folder and the dropdown filled with the name of the files in the folder like

```
JUN-2010,APR-2010,MAY-2010,SEP-2010,FEB-2011,DEC-2010
```

How can I sort this dropdownlist ?

Comment: Sort according to month-year or alphabetic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this following code.
where foldernames is list of strings.

```
 var s = from dt in foldernames
                    orderby DateTime.ParseExact(dt, "MMM-yyyy", culture) ascending
                   select( dt);
```

Bind var s in the dropdownlist.

Answer (score 0):

You can add those dates to [`List<DateTime>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) list and then use folowing:

```
list.Sort(delegate(DateTime x, DateTime y){ return y.CompareTo(x); });
```

then just attach to your dropdown.